# how to handle all changes in inputs

Tags: jquery, html

He,
I have problem to catch all changes in input elements, I dont now we but it work only in first element, and when I change number in other, nothing happens.

This is my html:

```
<td data-label="Ilość zam.">
   <form action="AddToCart" method="POST" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-target="#Amount">
   <input type="number" name=@product.ID.ToString() value="" id="Amount" />
   </form>
</td>
```

And this is ajax

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Amount').each(function () {
                $(this).change(updateQuantity)
            });
        });

        function updateQuantity(){   
            var $amount = $(this).val();
            var $id = $(this).attr("name");

            var settings = {
                url: "@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart")",
                data: { 'id': $id, 'quantity': $amount },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
                };

            $.ajax(settings);
```

So what is wrong????

Comment: `id`'s must be unique so `'$(#Amount').each` will only ever find one element. Use a `class`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Amongst other things, please read-over your message before posting and fix the worst of the typos. Perfect English is **not** a requirement, but we need to be able to understand the question and some of the above just looks like not taking the time rather than lack of knowledge.

Comment: Instead os using id attribute use the class attribute

Comment: what you want to do i think you have multiple input box and after change you want to get value of this input box. if i am right then ping me

Comment: Yes, class help for that case, thanks